# Sum of value of an attribute of preceding- siblings of ancestor

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml code

```html
<Table entityName="A">
  <tgroup cols="6">
   <colspec colwidth=".5in"/>
   <colspec colwidth=".25in"/>
   <colspec colwidth=".25in"/>
   <colspec colwidth="5in"/>
   <colspec colwidth=".25in"/>
   <colspec colwidth="1.25in"/>
   <tbody>
     <row>
    <entry/>
    <entry>
     <Para>1.</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry colspan="2">
     <Para>Amount paid</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry/>
    <entry/>
   </row>
   <row>
    <entry/>
    <entry colspan="3" padding="-1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt">
     <Para>seller. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry align="right" valign="bottom">
     <Para>$</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry align="right" padding="1pt 1pt 1pt 3pt" valign="bottom">
     <Para>
      <dwNumber>
       <DataItem/>
      </dwNumber>
     </Para>
    </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
    <entry/>
    <entry/>
    <entry>
     <Para>a)</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <Para>allocable</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry/>
    <entry/>
   </row>
   <row>
    <entry/>
    <entry/>
    <entry colspan="2" padding="-1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt">
     <Para>cooperative . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry align="right" valign="bottom">
     <Para>+ $</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry padding="1pt 1pt 1pt 3pt" valign="bottom">
     <Para>
      <dwNumber>
       <DataItem/>
      </dwNumber>
     </Para>
    </entry>
   </row>
   <row>
    <entry/>
    <entry>
     <Para>2.</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry colspan="2">
     <Para>Amount paid...........................</Para>
    </entry>
    <entry>
                  <Para>
      <dwNumber>
       <DataItem/>
      </dwNumber>
     </Para>
                </entry>
    <entry/>
   </row>
  </tbody>
 </tgroup>
</Table>
```

I need to find the actual column width(cell width) when ever there is a  in a cell through xsl. Right now what I am doing is counting the preceding entry elements and read colwidth attribute of the colspec element. But I can't do it anymore because of some of the columns are merged using colspan attribute of entry element. I need a way to get the sum of colspan attributes of the preceding-siblings and a count of how many entry elements actually have colspan attribute.

I am trying to do this inside a template which makes my current node "DataItem"

I am pretty new to xsl and spent a good day to find a way to do this.

I already tried using,

```html
<xsl:variable name="i">
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(ancestor::entry/preceding-sibling::entry[@colspan &gt; 0])"/>
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:variable name="i">
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(ancestor::entry/preceding-sibling::entry/@colspan)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Please show a [complete, minimal sample of your XSLT stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show what exactly the output should look like.

Comment: I edited my post in-response to your question. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the column at which an `entry` starts can be calculated (from the context of an `entry`) as:

```
<xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::entry) + sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@colspan) - count(preceding-sibling::entry/@colspan) + 1"/>
```

This is assuming there are no rowspans - otherwise it gets much more complex.

---

Here's a minimized example:

**XML**

```
<table>
    <row name="A">
        <cell colspan="3">A1, A2, A3</cell>
        <cell>A4</cell>
        <cell>A5</cell>
        <cell>A6</cell>
    </row>
    <row name="B">
        <cell>B1</cell>
        <cell>B2</cell>
        <cell colspan="2">B3, B4</cell>
        <cell>B5</cell>
        <cell>B6</cell>
    </row>
    <row name="C">
        <cell colspan="2">C1, C2</cell>
        <cell>C3</cell>
        <cell colspan="2">C4, C5</cell>
        <cell>C6</cell>
    </row>
</table>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cell">
    <cell start-col="{count(preceding-sibling::cell) + sum(preceding-sibling::cell/@colspan) - count(preceding-sibling::cell/@colspan) + 1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </cell>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <row name="A">
      <cell start-col="1">A1, A2, A3</cell>
      <cell start-col="4">A4</cell>
      <cell start-col="5">A5</cell>
      <cell start-col="6">A6</cell>
   </row>
   <row name="B">
      <cell start-col="1">B1</cell>
      <cell start-col="2">B2</cell>
      <cell start-col="3">B3, B4</cell>
      <cell start-col="5">B5</cell>
      <cell start-col="6">B6</cell>
   </row>
   <row name="C">
      <cell start-col="1">C1, C2</cell>
      <cell start-col="3">C3</cell>
      <cell start-col="4">C4, C5</cell>
      <cell start-col="6">C6</cell>
   </row>
</table>
```

---

### Edit:

> If I am at the entry at the time of calculation this could be right.
>   But I am trying to calculate 2/3 levels down. From the "DataItem" so I
>   have to use Ancestor::entry or something..which I still couldn't
>   figure out.

That should make very little difference. First, you could calculate the column number while you are at the `entry` level, and pass it down as a parameter. Alternatively, from the context of any descendant of an `entry`, you can use:

```
<xsl:variable name="preceding-entries" select="ancestor::entry/preceding-sibling::entry" />

<xsl:variable name="i" select="count($preceding-entries) + sum($preceding-entries/@colspan) - count($preceding-entries/@colspan) + 1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I am at the entry at the time of calculation this could be right. But I am trying to calculate 2/3 levels down. From the "DataItem" so I have to use Ancestor::entry or something..which I still couldn't figure out.

Comment: I already tried this one. Didn't work..but I will try the template method and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: "*I already tried this one. Didn't work..*" Well, it works for me - see [demo](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwy) - so you have probably not tried this one, but another one.

Comment: @micheal.hor257k yes, that's why I am trying to figure out why it isn't working. I tried your code still no luck :(

Comment: I should be able to get the correct value for $i just by adding,

<xsl:variable name="preceding-entries" select="ancestor::entry/preceding-sibling::entry" />

<xsl:variable name="i" select="count($preceding-entries) + sum($preceding-entries/@colspan) - count($preceding-entries/@colspan) + 1"/>

right?

Comment: Right. if you can't make it work, edit your question and show us. But please, remove all extraneous stuff; no one wants to wade through code that's not directly relevant to the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much @micheal.hor257k it worked. It's just a stupid mistake on my part.